# PhpSpreadsheet - How to set a chart 's series option is minor coordinate

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I am using PHPSpreadsheet to create a line chart.

Is there anywhere that I can set the minor or major coordinates on a series?

I have read the documentation and can't find the method. Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your expected result is? It would help others who are reading your question. Also, share code that you are currently using!

Comment: What I want to achieve is add one chart that it has two series:one is barchart(major) and another is linechart(minor), i want to set the line chart is minor coordinate like the office excel setting

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your specific issue and provide you with a good answer.